# Make an AJAX request from my phonegap app to servlet

Tags: ajax, servlets, cordova

I am trying to make an AJAX request from my phonegap app to a servlet running on my laptop.
It's hitting the server but the AJAX request is always going to error part. If I do the same request in a normal browser, it works fine.

```
\nfunction cred() { 
var username = "hisari";
var password = "kumar";
var ul = "ip ;  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: ul,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg, textstatus) {
        alert("success");
        if (msg.id != null) {
        }
                    else if (msg.error_id) {
            //Error
            alert('Error logging in:' + msg.error_message);
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error connecting to the servers" + error.message);
    }
});
}
```

Could you suggest what I can use instead of servlet for login validation?

Comment: You realize that you have a missing double quote. Is that a typo?

Comment: What is the response exactly? What would be displayed if you `console.log(msg);`?